# Joomla Easysocial user auto approvals while registration

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am using Easysocial Extension on my Joomla 3.0 site. i was able to successfully install and integrate it. But when ever a user get register i have to approve them to use the site. And don't want to approve every user, i want it in a auto mode. I have tried to Change the option for "New User Account Activation" to "None" under User Manager but No go. I have searcher for other options in Easysocial but not found any.

Can any one help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

1. Login to the admin panel of the Joomla Back-end
2. Go to: *Component > Easysocial > Settings > Profile types*
3. Select your members group
4. Go to the *Registration* tab
5. Select *Registration Type* and *Oauth Registration type* (various options are there)

Answer (score 0):

This may work, set these preferences in Joomla users > options

- Allow user registration - Yes
- New user registration Group - Registered
- New User Account activation - Self

User will now need to click an activation link which will then authenticate them.

Comment: OP Was asking about EasySocial registration not Joomla registration.